# Maven GPG plugin 3.0.0 is missing

Tags: maven-plugin, gnupg, maven-gpg-plugin

Here is maven-gpg-plugin version 3.0.0 official page: http://maven.apache.org/components/plugins-archives/maven-gpg-plugin-LATEST/download.cgi

However:

- the download links not working
- Maven central shows that the latest version of plugin is 1.6

Is it some fake page or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was stage release, which doesn't passed testing and voting on Maven Developers List, so was canceled.

https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r0286ef73b56cb484952489e6b5757e3b17023e73f8fa0dde7aa80bc4%40%3Cdev.maven.apache.org%3E

After testing two new issues was found:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MGPG-78
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MGPG-79

There is new plugin https://www.simplify4u.org/sign-maven-plugin/ probably it will be successor of `maven-gpg-plugin`

Comment: I am not sure I understand the implications of the fact that you mention, i.e. "testing was not successful". Are you saying that we can't use `maven-gpg-plugin` plugin anymore? But there's already version 3.0.1 https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/usage.html ... Can you clarify this? My IntelliJ IDE is saying `Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1' not found`, but I can still do `mvn clean install`. I am trying to understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe I know the problem. I never installed GnuPG manually. I thought maven would do that automatically. But after having read the documentation more carefully ([here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/usage.html)), I realise it's written that I should have `gpg` on the path.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72446441/3924118).