# Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1' not found

Tags: java, macos, maven

I've come across a project with a `pom.xml` file that contains the following

```
...
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.0.1</version>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                      <phase>verify</phase>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

...
```

So, this `pom.xml` file contains what is suggested in [the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/usage.html).

But my IntelliJ IDE is telling me

> Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1' not found

I tried to update the Maven indices, but this did not fix the issue.

I can still do `mvn clean install` (provided I comment a section related to the documentation, but this is another, I think unrelated, issue).

Of course, I never used this plugin and I don't know what `maven-gpg-plugin` actually does (well, I think it's used for signing software). I just wanted to run this project that I found, but, at the same time, I would not like to run it with these errors.

The [documentation of this plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/usage.html) explains that `gpg` should be on the path.

> Signs all of a project's attached artifacts with GnuPG.
>
> You need to have previously configured the default key.
>
> **`gpg` also needs to be on the search path.**

So, I realised that I had not installed manually GnuGP, and so that I didn't probably have `gpg` on the path. So, I thought I had to install it first, and that's what I did.

[Here](https://gnupg.org/download/index.html) are the instructions on how to install it.

I am on a mac, so I tried to find a `brew` formula to install it - [here](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/gpg-suite) it is. So, I did `brew install --cask gpg-suite` (and I have now `gpg` on the path), but this did not solve the problem.

Why am I having this problem, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

try "Invalidate caches & Restart"!!